# Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: fork/exec /usr/bin/docker-compose-v1: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I get this error when trying to start docker-compose by Docker Desktop v4.12.0.
docker-compose up runs in terminal normally.

Answer (score 3):

Settings->General->Enable Docker Compose V1/V2 compatibility mode (check and restart Docker desktop)